# Returning the latitude and longitude of a default marker taken from string location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

My question is how to take the latitude and longitude of an existing marker? Let me explain: When I enter on a page on the browser I display the marker position using the address:

```
  <ng-map ng-if="null != evaluation" default-style="false" zoom="16" center="{{ '{{ getAddress() }}' }}" style="width: 100%; height: 430px;">
                <marker centered="true" position="{{ '{{ getMarkerPosition() }}' }}" draggable="true" on-dragend="onMarkerDragEnd($event)"></marker>
  </ng-map>
```

Angular part:

```
  $scope.getMarkerPosition = function () {
            if (!$scope.address.mapPinLocationLatitude || !$scope.address.mapPinLocationLongitude) {
                return $scope.getAddress();
            }
            return [$scope.address.mapPinLocationLatitude, $scope.address.mapPinLocationLongitude]
        };


   $scope.getAddress = function () {
            //building the adress by getting the objects that are used for creating an address object

            return streetString + ', ' + address; //streetString will be a string that has the complete address
        };

    $scope.onMarkerDragEnd = function ($event) {
            $scope.address.mapPinLocationLatitude = $event.latLng.lat();
            $scope.address.mapPinLocationLongitude = $event.latLng.lng();

        uptadeRegions();
        };
```

If I move the marker the lat and log exists, the method getMarkerPosition returning an array with the 2 of it. But if I don't move the marker on map, how to obtain the lat and long? The default are 0 and I don't know how to resolve it. Thank you,

EDIT:

```
app.controller('MapController',
['$scope', 'NgMap','$state', 'SelectOptionsService', '$rootScope', '$q','GeoCoder',
    function ($scope, NgMap, $state, SelectOptionsService, $rootScope, $q, GeoCoder) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you use an address for the marker position, and you want to get lat & lng during it's initialized? you could use the `GeoCoder` service (provided by ngMap)

something like:

```
app.controller('MapController',
['$scope', 'NgMap','$state', 'SelectOptionsService', '$rootScope', '$q','GeoCoder',
    function ($scope, NgMap, $state, SelectOptionsService, $rootScope, $q, GeoCoder) {
        //hired by marker:geo-callback
        $scope.geoCallback = function() {
            GeoCoder.geocode({
              address: $scope.getAddress()
            }).then(function(result) {
              //explore this, you may got the position in: result[0].geometry.location
              console.log('A place object is: ', result);
            });
        };
       ...
       //your getAddress function
       $scope.getAddress = function() {
       };
}]);
```

and in html, in marker you can use the `geo-callback` attribute

```
<marker ... geo-callback="geoCallback()"></marker>
```

read about [geo-callback here](https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/docs/marker.html)

Comment: I don't know how exactly to inject in controller

Comment: like `app.controller('TestCtrl1', ['$scope', 'GeoCoder', function ($scope, GeoCoder) {}]`, how do you define your controller?

Comment: I put this code in no function $scope, and maybe it s not seeing it.. where exactly I need to put this?

Comment: in your controller, update your question's code with the controller definition, and I'll add it there

Comment: @IleNea You already defined the $scope.getAddress() in your code, ...I updated the answer with more detail

Comment: It gives me the error: Cannot read property 'geocode' of undefined

Comment: @IleNea awesome, should be `result[0].geometry.location`